# Redirecting orders by company field

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

i want to setup a store with multiple store manager with WooCommerce. So when logged in customer make an order, I want that order to be assigned to specific store manager by company field. For example, if customer company is idk 0001, show that order to shop manager id 1 only in admin area. When customer company is set to 0002, show that order to shop manager id 2 only. I saw some solutions but non of them worked for me like this. I assume that I will need two functions? One for assigning orders and one for filtering? Also, the best option will be filtering by store manager user name.

Comment: You're going to have to code this up yourself as far as I can tell.  This is going to require customer & shop manager (user roles) meta data that is custom to your site.  Once you have successfully assigned that data then you should be able to find info on how to filter posts (orders) using custom values.

Comment: Second option is when certain shop manager loads admin orders area that is only display orders which contain 0001 for example. When I do that by hand it only sorts that orders out but I want that automatic on load. So maybe function that enters search criteria on load by current user...